# How to display date value in XSLT transformation

Tags: java, xml, rest, xslt, xmlgregoriancalendar

My UI supplies the user selected date in milliseconds to the backend rest layer.

For e.g Say the user selects "07/11/2018" from the UI then it gets passed on to the REST layer as milliseconds '1541509200000'. And the REST layer maps this value to a 'XMLGregorianCalendarObject' within my DTO.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;

public class PersonDetails implements Serializable
{

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.dateOfBirth = value;
    }

}
```

And this DTO gets converted to an XML and stored. The XML payload looks like below :

```
    <personDetails>
       <dateOfBirth>2018-11-06Z</dateOfBirth>
    </personDetails>
```

I have the below  XSLT code which is currently just displaying the above dateOfBirth element :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <div>
            <div> Date of birth: </div>
            <div> <xsl:value-of select="//personDetails/dateOfBirth" /> </div>
        </div>
</xsl:template>
```

And it generates the output

```
Date of birth: 2018-11-06Z
```

What should i do to display the dateOfBirth as the original user selected 07/11/2018 in the XSLT transformation .

Comment: So why does your system translate the input of `07/11/2018` to `1541509200000` (which I believe stands for `2018-11-06T13:00`) ? Shouldn't  you fix the problem at the origin?

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates. You must manipulate the input using string functions:

```
<xsl:template match="personDetails">    
    <div>
        <div> Date of birth: </div>
        <div>
            <!-- day-->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(dateOfBirth, 9, 2)" />
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <!-- month-->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(dateOfBirth, 6, 2)" />
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <!-- year-->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(dateOfBirth, 1, 4)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Am using XSLT 2.0 . And the above suggested solution won't work in my case as the client would have selected a date of 7/11/2018 , but value that the XML gets stored is '2018-11-06Z' . So if I do a substring of this value then the value displayed will be like 06/11/2018  .....which is not what the user has anyway selected

Comment: If you use XSLT 2.0, then you can use its `format-date()` function to format the date to your liking. -- I am afraid you have lost me on the 2nd point. If all you have is the XML, and the XML says `2018-11-06Z`, then how would you know what the user selected originally? Is there a known, constant offset?